# How to parse this specific XML from HttpResponse in Android?

Tags: android, xml, httpresponse

I'm new in Android development. I made an Android app for login in a website. The login page takes three inputs 'username', 'password' & 'pin'.
I've successfully passed these data using HttpPost method. See the code,

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com/api/service.php");

try {
    // Add user name, password & pin
    String action = "login";

    EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
    String username = uname.getText().toString();

    EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
    String password = pword.getText().toString();

    EditText pcode = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.txt_pin);
    String pin = pcode.getText().toString();

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", action));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pin", pin));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    Log.w("PS", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Now i want to parse the `'ack'` & `'msg'` from HttpResponse which is a XML output appears after passing data to the website. See here,

```
<login>
<member>
<id/>
<username/>
<name/>
<ewallpoints/>
<ack>FAILED</ack>
<msg>Wrong Username and Password</msg>
</member>
</login>
```

Comment: Java Provider Dom or sax parser, e.g. http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/12/parse-xml-file-in-java-example-tutorial.html

Comment: thanks for the reply, i've checked the link its very useful but its parsing XML in offline mode, can you tell me how i can parse XML directly from the http response ???

Answer (score 0):

Use `response.getEntity().getContent()` to get an input stream and process it with DOM, SAX or XPath as @tobias suggested. There are many options.

You may also get the xml string directly. Change the line

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

to

```
String xml = httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler());
```